# How to implement np.convolve in C#?

Tags: python, c#, numpy, numsharp

I am working on porting a python application, used for optical fiber analysis, to C#.
As the original code relies heavily on Numpy, it was decided to use Num-sharp for the port but, later, it was found the np.convolve is not fully developed yet in the library.

Is there a way this method could be implemented to C#? Tried to do this by running it with the help of IronPython but now I am facing problems with memory leaks (after running the function several times, memory reaches 1GB).

This is what Visual Studio shows me after function is already finished, and just ran once.
[Visual Studio Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NH7K.jpg)

**Edit:** I am trying something different to make a workaround for this. Tried to used IronPython from a different AppDomain but, this time, I am getting errors as NDArray from NumSharp is not defined as serialized.
Is there a way to define a external class instance as marshalbyref?

Comment: `np.convolve` is just a thinly-veiled double for loop, I would think it would be trivial to implement in C#.